# What does RegOpenKeyExA() substitute for in uwp programs

Tags: uwp

I need a function with the same functionality as RegOpenKeyExA () that I can use in uwp programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the document for [RegOpenKeyExA method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa), this method is used to open the specified registry key. This is not allowed in pure UWP apps. UWP apps are running inside
the sandbox and UWP apps can't access or modify the registry key. So there is no method in UWP that can do the same thing as RegOpenKeyExA method.